# JQuery Accordion - link from panel to panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I've read 100 different posts on JQuery accordions, but none seem to address what I think is a super simple task.

My simplified accordion is as follows:

```
Panel 1
  Section 1.1
  Section 1.2

Panel 2
  Section 2.1
  <link back to Panel 1, Section 1.2>
```

I would like the link to close Panel 2, Open Panel 1 and scroll to Section 1.2. I have tried linking using basic #anchors but the links either don't fire or if they do, they refresh the entire page. I just want to link from panel to panel within 1 accordion. The end use is a FAQ where the links are something to the effect of (see also: blah blah on Panel 1).

Markup:

```
<div id="accordion" class="accordion">
   <h1>Panel 1</h1>
   <div>
      <h3>Section 1.1</h3>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, susceros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur     malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
   <h3>Section 1.2</h3>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, susceros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>

   </div>
   <h1>Panel 2</h1>
   <div>
      <h3>Section 2.1</h3>
    <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
      <p><a href="">LINK BACK TO PANEL 1 - SECTION 2 - should collapse Panel 2, open Panel 1, scroll to  Section 2</a></p>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Jquery (1.9.1):

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      heightStyle: "content",
      active: false,
      collapsible: true 
    });
  });
```

Link to JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/freemars/L2Wy7/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L2Wy7/2/) using the "active" option.

JS

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
                             heightStyle: "content",
                                  active: false,
                             collapsible: true 
                            });

$( '#clickme' ).on('click', function(){
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", 0 );
});
```

Comment: That is great and will pretty much do the job for any of the shorter panels. However, is there any way to scroll to a particular portion in the panel, say to a specific id?

Comment: With the 'active' command you only open up a particular section of the accordion, not "focus" on a particular line.